# Selected Data from database to controller Variable

Tags: sql, model-view-controller

Is there any way that my Selected data from database can be assigned to my controller variable? I'm using "Select * From" statement

Comment: ehmm, where to start.. usually programmers use an ORM-framework (Object-Relational-mapping). That way you can let the framework map between the records in the tables (relational tables) and objects (program environment). And if your application will be large, you can even decide to improve loosely coupling by having separate Data-Models and View-Models (thus the data-structure in your views are loosely coupled with the data-structure in the database). By the way, which programming language are you using?

Comment: @inco hi thank you for you response. I'm currently using c# mvc. This is the first time I'm using it for a project my proffessor gave to me and right now I'm having trouble in it. I tried using query to access the database

`"SELECT SubjectCode FROM Subjects WHERE Schedule = '" + @subject.Schedule + "' EXCEPT SELECT SubjectCode FROM Subjects WHERE SubjectCode = '" + @currentval.Replace("'", "''") + "'"` but after this line I don't know how to retrieve it and put it in an array variable to use it. Is there anything that i can do?

Comment: Perhaps this is a useful tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application  Using something that maps between the tables and objects for you will be very convenient when the amount of tables grow. And when performance dictates (usually with batch-operations) you can always fall back to custom written SQL.

Comment: By the way, when you configure your MVC-application (and Entity Framework) correctly, your application should be safe from SQL-injections. Just read what mommy did here: https://xkcd.com/327/ When you build od the SQL-queries yourself, it is easy to break these safeguards. (you only need one user to enter an apostrophe, ending the current query, and adding the syntax of a second query. And without knowing, you perform two queries on the database instead of only the one you intended.